# Using index on join

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

Using EXPLAIN for the query below shows

```
SELECT cha.cid AS cid,
       cha.data AS dl
FROM cha, c_users
WHERE uid = 808
AND cha.cid = c_users.cid;
```

1. it does a full scan on `cha` table
2. uses the multi column index(`cid`,`uid`) from `c_users`.

Why doesn't it not use the primary key index from `cha` and rather does a full table scan. Is there a better way to optimise the query/table.

Edit:
cha.cid is my primary key. Added after the comment below.

Comment: Is `cha.cid` your primary key?

Comment: yeah cha.cid is a primary key

Comment: I've found that splitting it into two queries and creating the appropriate indexes was better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal BTREE, and an index on (cid,uid), a scan will be needed if you don't specify cid and only search for uid. An index on (uid,cid) (notice the order) would / could help.

This is by no means a guarantee it will be used, MySQL can guess that a full scan might be quicker (continuous read) if a certain index / join most likely will require a certain large percentage of the index to be used, and other reasons. You can check with `FORCE INDEX` if using the key compared to a scan is actually any quicker or not (disable query cache on a testserver before testing this).

Comment: Nothing to do with being BTREE - covering indexes need to match the leftmost columns in the defined order.  If the first one doesn't match, the index won't be considered.

Comment: My bad, was confusing it with the standard 2 integer spatial index trick (RTREE), which of course has nothing to do with the problem at hand, was just a personal brainfart, and would still require both integer to have some sort of bounds. In my defence: it was very late here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create an index for uid column.

When you ask question about performance, output of EXPLAIN and CREATE TABLE statements makes things much easier for helpers. Please add them next time.

Comment: I've described the output from EXPLAIN. Will you need more info ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `cha` doesn't have a [covering index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)#Covering_Index) available for this query it has to access the data pages anyway to retrieve some of the data it needs.  Based on table statistics, the optimizer has decided that the IO time of first scanning the index and then jumping to the data pages is like to be worse than just scanning the table.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't...

```
SELECT cha.cid AS cid,
       cha.data AS dl
    FROM cha INNER JOIN c_users ON cha.cid = c_users.cid
    WHERE uid = 808;
```

be more idiomatic?

(Edited to take account on knittl's comment).

Comment: syntax is `FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON …`, not with a comma